# Help catching AV with WinDbg and ADPlus 7.0

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, windbg, access-violation, adplus

I want to catch Memory Access Violation in SQL Server Compact Edition like this described at
http://debuggingblog.com/wp/2009/02/18/memory-access-violation-in-sql-server-compact-editionce/
The suggested config is:

```
<ADPlus>
   <Settings>
     <RunMode>CRASH</RunMode>
     <Option>Quiet</Option>
     <ProcessName>MyApp.exe</ProcessName>
   </Settings>
   <Exceptions>
     <Option>NoDumpOnFirstChance</Option>
     <Config>
       <Code>clr;av</Code><!–to get the full dump on clr access violation–>
       <Actions1>FullDump</Actions1>
       <ReturnAction1>gn</ReturnAction1>
     </Config>
   </Exceptions>
</ADPlus>
```

I download latest Debugging Tools and observe what Microsoft rewrite adplus tool into managed code and change syntax of config File.
I rewrite config file like this:

```
 <ADPlus  Version="2">
 <Settings>
  <RunMode>Crash</RunMode>
  <Option>Quiet</Option>
  <Option>NoDumpOnFirst</Option>
  <Sympath>c:\symbols\</Sympath>
  <OutputDir>c:\work\output\</OutputDir>
  <ProcessName>c:\work\app\output\MyApp.exe</ProcessName>
 </Settings> 

 <Exceptions><!--to get the full dump on clr access violation-->
  <Exception Code="clr;av">   
   <Actions1>FullDump</Actions1>
   <ReturnAction1>gn</ReturnAction1>
  </Exception>  
 </Exceptions>
</ADPlus>
```

And I get error "Couldn't find exception with code: clr;av". If I understand right It didn't load sos extension, but I can't find the right section and syntax that I should use to load it.

adplus_old.vbs - for some reasons didn't launch process on Windows 7.
WinDBG 6.12.0002.633 X86
ADPlus Engine Version: 7.01.002 02/27/2009

Maybe someone has a working example of config of debugging .NET app with latest adplus.exe?

Answer (score 1):

This should load SOS.dll for you (if you are using framework v1, the  is `<cmd>.load clr10\sos.dll</cmd>`):

```
 <ADPlus  Version="2"> 
 <precommands>
    <cmd>.loadby sos mscorwks</cmd>
 </precommands>

 <Settings> 
  <RunMode>Crash</RunMode> 
  <Option>Quiet</Option> 
  <Option>NoDumpOnFirst</Option> 
  <Sympath>c:\symbols\</Sympath> 
  <OutputDir>c:\work\output\</OutputDir> 
  <ProcessName>c:\work\app\output\MyApp.exe</ProcessName> 
 </Settings>  

 <Exceptions><!--to get the full dump on clr access violation--> 
  <Exception Code="clr;av">    
   <Actions1>FullDump</Actions1> 
   <ReturnAction1>gn</ReturnAction1> 
  </Exception>   
 </Exceptions> 
</ADPlus>
```

Comment: I'm tried this variant.
ADPlus v7.0 doesn't understand cmd tag.

"    Errors reading configuration file: c:\work\adplus.cfg
      Invalid tag in the precommands section of a configuration string: cmd"

But I found workaround. I use DebugDiag software which is doing the same job.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) documentation for ADPlus: exception code should be hex value of error code. For instance, if you want to capture AV - you need 0xC0000005

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/capturing-adplus-clr-crashes) about capturing error dumps for CLR

Comment: These links refered to old ADPlus.vbs, which is broken on Windows 7. ADPlus v7.0 change config syntax.
I use DebugDiag as workaround.